# What Shipyard has the most parts?

Tags: starfield

Each area with a starship services let's you build and modify your ship, but they are not all equal in what parts they offer. So I'd build at one shipyard, but not have nice looking parts and then have to find another service to hopefully finish putting it together(and usually have to end up rebuilding because the previous parts don't line up anymore...).

Is there a Starship Services that offers the most if not every part available to me?

Answer (score 1):

No. All star services techs have limited selections.

First off, large settlements like Akira and Jemison will have all categories of components available for you to buy. Smaller settlements will have decreased selections. Small civilian settlements, both procedurally generated ones and the ones that are shown on the system map, may have an extremely limited selection -- eg only weapons; the last civilian outpost I visited only had 2 weapons systems and 4 total structural components at all.

Then in terms of 'quality' -- "better" components and weapons are available in higher level systems. Jemison is in a level 1 system (Alpha Centauri), and so it has the most basic components.

Finally, when you're exploring the United Colonies or Freestar Collective worlds, there are some brands affiliated with each of those factions. Deimos supplies ships for the UC Navy, so Deimos components are available on UC worlds, but I've not seen them on Freestar worlds. Similarly Stroud components seem to be primarily available on Freestar worlds, and I've not found them at all on UC planets. (This being odd because Walter Stroud-Eklund hangs around the Constellation Lodge in UC space.) There are also some brands which seem to be always available like Light Scythe weapons (lasers). I've not found a pattern to what's available on unaffiliated colonies.

So if you like the look of a certain brand, you may need to stick to a certain faction's worlds. Otherwise, if you're looking for the 'best' weapons/shields/engines/etc., check out outposts on higher level worlds. And civilian outposts seem to be a dice roll: generally comparable quality to other outposts of the same level, but actual stock will be limited and seems random.

Comment: Similarly, building your own "Landing Pad with Shipbuilder" in your own outpost also has most components but not all of them—especially the more 'specialized' components.